# How to execute command in linux desktop environment without a terminal application?

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, console, gui

I installed cinnamon to arch linux without any console or terminal application. And set sddm to auto start. So how do I execute a command now ?

Comment: ctr+alt+f1, login and run what you want.

Comment: @lpor-sircer no any response

Comment: I don't use Cinnamon but this is quite common among desktop environments: Alt + F2.

Comment: How did you manage the install without any terminal/console?

Comment: @lpor-sircer Before cinnamon, I have not any desktop environtment. So I boot to the terminal mode directly.

Comment: @lpor-sircer Ctrl+Alt+F2 worked.